# Button Click Not Fired on Move Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, draggable, drag

I'm trying to move the Button inside my application, It's working fine but the ButtonClick event  is not firing now.

**Code :**

**XAML**

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="190,108,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75" MouseLeftButtonUp="button1_MouseLeftButtonUp"
            MouseMove="button1_MouseMove" MouseUp="button1_MouseUp" Click="button1_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.PreviewMouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseUp);
        button1.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler
                                              (button1_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        button1.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseMove);
    }
double m_MouseX;
double m_MouseY;
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.PreviewMouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseUp);
        button1.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        button1.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseMove);
    }
private void button1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the Position of Window so that it will set margin from this window
        m_MouseX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        m_MouseY = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
    }

    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            // Capture the mouse for border
            e.MouseDevice.Capture(button1);
            System.Windows.Thickness _margin = new System.Windows.Thickness();
            int _tempX = Convert.ToInt32(e.GetPosition(this).X);
            int _tempY = Convert.ToInt32(e.GetPosition(this).Y);
            _margin = mainGrd.Margin;
            // when While moving _tempX get greater than m_MouseX relative to usercontrol 
            if (m_MouseX > _tempX)
            {
                // add the difference of both to Left
                _margin.Left += (_tempX - m_MouseX);
                // subtract the difference of both to Left
                _margin.Right -= (_tempX - m_MouseX);
            }
            else
            {
                _margin.Left -= (m_MouseX - _tempX);
                _margin.Right -= (_tempX - m_MouseX);
            }
            if (m_MouseY > _tempY)
            {
                _margin.Top += (_tempY - m_MouseY);
                _margin.Bottom -= (_tempY - m_MouseY);
            }
            else
            {
                _margin.Top -= (m_MouseY - _tempY);
                _margin.Bottom -= (_tempY - m_MouseY);
            }
            mainGrd.Margin = _margin;
            m_MouseX = _tempX;
            m_MouseY = _tempY;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.MouseDevice.Capture(null);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HI");
    }
```

**button1_Click** never fires, any suggestions.
Is I'm doing something wrong or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: change `RoutedEventArgs e` to `EventArgs e`

Comment: @neiiic does not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prevents your `button1_Click` from firing:

```
e.MouseDevice.Capture(null);
```

I assume that you want the messagebox to show only when you click the button without dragging it.

I would remove the MouseUp event and instead use:

**XAML**

```
PreviewMouseDown="Button1_OnPreviewMouseDown"
```

**C#**

```
    double m_MouseX;
    double m_MouseY;
    double m_ClickedX;
    double m_ClickedY;
```

[...]

```
    private void Button1_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        m_ClickedX = m_MouseX;
        m_ClickedY = m_MouseY;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_ClickedX == m_MouseX && m_ClickedY == m_MouseY)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("HI");
        }
    }
```

The if statement checks if you have moved the button or not and only shows the MessageBox if the button has not been moved.

Comment: Still the same not firing

Comment: That's weird, mine is firing without a hitch. Here's my complete code: http://pastebin.com/wAknPqZV

Comment: got it forgot to remove the event from constructor

Comment: Can I throw another query?

Comment: Sure, I guess. is it related to this? Have you asked it on SO already?

Comment: yes I have around 15-20 buttons and I want the same thing to be done on all the buttons but didnt achieved much so shall I ask another ques or a chat in chat room will be fine?

Comment: Well you have it working for one button so shouldn't be too much work to add more buttons. You should even be able to reuse positioning variables and MouseDown event.

Comment: no what I wanted was to get all the buttons on initialization of  the class n bind the events instead of defining the events on XAML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84487/discussion-between-arijit-mukherjee-and-richnau).

Comment: Hi there? Its giving some issues